# C# Unity не меняется значение переменных в скрипте префаба

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп

Задача такая, спавнятся кубы раз в t время и двигаются вперед с определенной скоростью. Скорость я редактирую в текстовом поле (InputField). Создал префаб куба и набросил скрпит движения. Скрипт спавна набросил на MainCamera. Когда я ввожу значение в текстовое поле, то они везде приходят,а Update не меняется. Вопрос, как менять значение speed , чтоб оно менялось Online?

фрагмент кода на камере

```
public class One : MonoBehaviour
{
   float   speed=2f, stepLength=10f;
   float timeCreate = 1f;
   public GameObject box;
   public Test test;
   public Transform point;

   public void ReadStringInputSpeed(string str) 
   {
       speed = float.Parse(str);
   }
   void Update()
   {
       print("Time " + timeCreate);
       test.SpeedInCube(speed);
   }
...
```

скрит в префабе

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CubeMover cubeMover;

    float stepLength = 2f , speed = 3f ;

    void Update()
    {
        print("speed in Update " + speed);
    }
    public void SpeedInCube(float t)
    {
        speed = t;
        print("speed in function " + speed);

    }
```

Изменения в консоле есть, когда ввожу значение, но в update значение неизменно
[image]

Comment: есть подозрение, что у вас куча одинаковых логов и юнити их склеила. апдейт делается чаще чем раз в 2 секунды, поэтому или у вас много объектов и в логах они перемешались, или что-то совсем не так с инстанциированием. фрагмент кода который показали работать должен. (но каждый апдейт менять скорость архитектурно не очень хорошо)

Comment: Объектов не много, не работает именно у префабов, объекты на сцене работают корректно, может быть я не так спавню префабы?

Comment: добавьте в функцию SpeedInCube лог до присваивания. будет понятнее что на что меняется.

Comment: Все, ты меня направил в нужную сторону

Comment: Тут нужно видеть как ты спавнишь и передаёшь скорость